# Must iCloud notify shared calender users of every change?

Tags: icloud, calendar

If I share an iCloud calendar with other iCloud users, then every user is notified of every single change to any event that somebody else makes.  They show up in the "Inbox" of Calendar Apps.  Here is a little screenshot from Mac Calendar.app:
[image]

In my usage scenario, this makes no sense. There are too many changes to this calendar all the time. Can this be disabled somewhere?

- Just imagine what happens upon adding a couple of thousand (past) events in a shared calendar.  iCloud is choking.
- Shared Calendars on Google and other platforms don't seem to have that feature at all.
- It seems to be a cloud feature.  Reading the notification (e.g. by clicking "OK" in Calendar.app) makes the notification disappear in other apps (e.g. Fantastical, iCloud Web Calender) too.
- This is not about invitations, or about the various alerts that can be configured in notification center.  I know that I can silence notifications for shared calendars, but they still show up in the Calendar Inbox.

On iCloud.com there is a setting that looks like it could be relevant, but I have it disabled and this did not change anything.  Here's how it looks in German:

[image]

The second one says "Notify me about updates to shared calendars" which sounds like it would disable what I'm seeing, but it does not.